# Lexical or Preprocessor Issue in Swift3

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, xcode8, lexical

When migrating swift 2.3 to swift 3

In module.modulemap happens 
Redefinition of module 'dnssd' error.

*Previously defined here( in swift 2.3)*

```
module dnssd [system] {
    header "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/include/dns_sd.h"
    export *
}
```

*Redefined here( in swift 3)*

```
module dnssd [system] [extern_c] {
    header "dns_sd.h"
    export *
}
```

How to solve this error? Please help me.

Comment: I did but can't solve the error in my code. Anyway thank you @matt